# Display data from code behind in jQuery Modal Window

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog, code-behind

On a button click I open a jQuery modal window from code behind in asp.net c#

```
    protected void btnShowModal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Show Modal Popup", "showmodalpopup();", true);
    }
```

Here's the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showmodalpopup() {
    $("#popupdiv").dialog({
        title: "Personal Information",
        width: 500,
        height: 450,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Here's the html:

```
<div id="popupdiv" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none">
First Name:<br />
Last Name:<br />
Agent No:<br />
Phone:<br />
Email:<br />
Address 1:<br />
Address 2:<br />
City:<br />
State:<br />
Zip:<br />
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnShowModal" runat="server" Text="Contact Information" OnClick="btnShowModal_Click" /> <asp:Button ID="Messages" runat="server" Text="Inbox" OnClick="btnShowModal_Click" />
```

On the code behind I have the data loaded from db.

```
            string lastName = tbl.Rows[0]["lastname"].ToString();
            string fullName = tbl.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString();
            string Phone = tbl.Rows[0]["phone"].ToString();
            string email = tbl.Rows[0]["email"].ToString();
            string address1 = tbl.Rows[0]["address1"].ToString();
            string address2 = tbl.Rows[0]["address2"].ToString();
            string city = tbl.Rows[0]["city"].ToString();
            string State = tbl.Rows[0]["State"].ToString();
            string Zip = tbl.Rows[0]["Zip"].ToString();
```

**What I'm trying to accomplish is to display the data grabbed from database in the modal window from code behind.** 
Contact info here is hard coded. This is just to show an example.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Is the data in the document (DOM) yet or not? If not, then opening your modal will need to trigger an AJAX call. If so, then opening your model needs to extract it using the appropriate selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `Label` for each value in your Modal code, like this:

```
<div id="popupdiv" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none">
    First Name: <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
    Last Name: <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
    Agent No: <asp:Label ID="lblAgentNo" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
    Phone: <asp:Label ID="lblPhine" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
    Email: <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
    Address 1: <asp:Label ID="lblAddress1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
    Address 2: <asp:Label ID="lblAddress2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
    City: <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
    State: <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
    Zip: <asp:Label ID="lblZip" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
</div>
```

Then in CodeBehind set value for this Labels:

```
protected void btnShowModal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Show Modal Popup", "showmodalpopup();", true);
    string firstName = tbl.Rows[0]["firstName"].ToString();
    string lastName = tbl.Rows[0]["lastName"].ToString();
    //
    //
    // and so on

    lblFirstName.Text = firstName;
    lblLastName.Text = lastName;
    //
    //
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: Short and simple! Thank you!